# Find the hightest value in a line of a file with multlines

Tags: bash, perl, awk

I have a file with different lines and would like to find and output the hightest value in each line starting from the second column. It is possible in bash or awk ?

For instance the file has this format structure

```
136   0.369326 0.004999
137   0.003199 0.140172 0.055189 0.047191 0.520696 0.172565
138   0.000400 0.021596 0.095381 0.179164 0.065187
...
and so on"
```

And I would like the following output

```
136   0.369326
137   0.520696
138   0.179164
... and so on
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please [edit] your post and show us the code you already have and also tell us how it fails to do what you want?

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible in all of the tools that you've tagged your question with. It's trivial, for example, in Perl.

But Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service and you've shown us no evidence that you have written any code to solve the problem, so I'm not going to give you a solution. Here's some pseudocode that you can use as the design for your solution.

```
WHILE you can read a line from the file
  SPLIT the input record on whitespace
  PRINT the first element of the split record
  CALCULATE the maximum value of the remaining element
  PRINT the maximum value
END WHILE
```

So you would need to know how to do the following things:

- Read a record of data from a file
- Split a string on whitespace
- Print data
- Find the maximum in a list of values

Answer (score 0):

As you tagged for Perl:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw(max);

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my($key, @numbers) = split(/\s+/);
    print "${key}\t", max(@numbers), "\n";
}

__DATA__
136   0.369326 0.004999
137   0.003199 0.140172 0.055189 0.047191 0.520696 0.172565
138   0.000400 0.021596 0.095381 0.179164 0.065187
```

Test run:

```
$ perl dummy.pl
136     0.369326
137     0.520696
138     0.179164
```

Comment: Hello, thank you all for your help. I tagged the perl language with bash and awk because I thought it would be easier to find a solution to my simple problem. I am not a programmer (but I try to do at best with what I know as the bash / awk language or possibly fortran). By bringing me your help with your perl approach you have helped me a lot and more importantly I learned. the code you wrote me will help me if I have another similar problem of the same kind. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Perl one-liner

```
$ cat stephane.txt
136   0.369326 0.004999
137   0.003199 0.140172 0.055189 0.047191 0.520696 0.172565
138   0.000400 0.021596 0.095381 0.179164 0.065187

$ perl -lane ' @x=sort {$a<$b} @F[1..$#F]; print "$F[0] $x[0]" ' stephane.txt
136 0.369326
137 0.520696
138 0.179164

$
```